# Must consider things for every smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

When creating smart contract from scratch, what kind of things you should consider? 
For example:
1.Certain functions should be accessible only by creator/specific addresses

2.Fallback function

Is there anything else that you must consider before event starting creating a contract?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question and I almost voted to close this as 'too broad'. The answer also depends quite much on what other assumptions we make about the business case.

So something like the following might be required as well:

1) Do you want to implement your business case with a blockchain at all? If yes, is Ethereum the right choice? Private or public Ethereum?

2) How will you write the contract, what testing framework will you use, how will you deploy the contract?

3) Should the contract be upgradable, should it use a proxy pattern, how are you planning to "update" it?

4) Does your contract have..well, bugs? Re-entrancy attack? Other security vulnerabilities?

5) Is usage of the contract feasible (gas wise)? How much do users need to pay to interact with your contract? Who are the end users and where do you get them?

And so on.

Comment: Already helping me here. Thanks
1. I believe so. Good old document verification.
2. No idea.. Will do some more research on things you mentioned here.
3. Haven't even thought of it. Will have to look at it.
4. Testing for security. Noted
5. Gas prices, price per user is into consideration and one of the main things I'm trying to optimize.